# Existence test in 3 level of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
In [32]: mydict
Out[32]: 
{'Foo': {'DendriticCells': {'LV.ip': [15.14,1.003],
   'SP.ip': [16.0282,3.001]},
  'Macrophages': {'LV.ip': [32.137260000000005],
   'SP.ip': [34.020810000000004]},
  'NKCells': {'LV.ip': [4.89852], 'SP.ip': [5.18562]}}}
```

Given a string that correspond to key level 3, what I want to do to have a construct 
to check the existence in the dictionary based on `choices` below.
What's the way to do it. I tried this but failed.

```
choice1 = "LV.ip"
choice2 = "KK.ip"
choices = [choice1,choice2]
celltypes = ["DendriticCells",  "Macrophages", "NKCells"]
for ch in choices:
    for ct in celltypes:
        if mydict["Foo"][ct][choices]:
            print "THERE\n"
        else:
            print "Not there\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

You might want to do something like `mydict.get("Foo", {}).get(ct, {}).get(ch):`. Essentially get a default empty `dict` that will default onto nothing towards the end.

Alternatively, use `in` to verify the keys.  You might have something like

```
if ct in mydict['foo'] and ch in mydict['foo'][ct]:
```

Which should not fail due to lazy evaluation in Python.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `if` statement should use `ch`, not `choices`
2. You should break up the test in that `if`; for example, make sure that `mydict["Foo"][ct]` exists before trying to see if it contains anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function and `in` operator to check if the key exists in the dictionary or not.

```
for choice in choices:
    for key in my_dict:
        if any(choice in my_dict[key][key1] for key1 in my_dict[key]):
            print "{} is there".format(choice)
```

**Output**

```
LV.ip is there
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable name

```
choice1 = "LV.ip"
choice2 = "KK.ip"
choices = [choice1,choice2]
celltypes = ["DendriticCells",  "Macrophages", "NKCells"]
for ch in choices:
    for ct in celltypes:
        if mydict["Foo"][ct][ch]: // change choices to ch
            print "THERE\n"
        else:
            print "Not there\n"
```